# Sending a PDF file using Refit in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new in using API. I would like to know if there is a proper way of sending a PDF file using an API key that is converted to Base64. End point information is on the screenshot link.

Comment: you need to create a Refit interface that matches the API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class PdfFile
{
    [JsonProperty("file")]
    public File File { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [JsonProperty("mime")]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public string Base64Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then an Interface looking something like:

```cs
[Post("/upload")]
Task UploadPdf([Body]PdfFile file, [Header("x-axa-api-key")] string apiKey);
```

then your upload code would look something like this

```cs
var pdfApi = RestService.For<IPdfApi>("https://goodmorning-axa-dev.azure-api.net");

var pdf = new PdfFile();
var file = new File();

file.MimeType = "application/pdf";
file.Base64Data= "base64-data="; // append base64 encoded data here

pdf.File = file;

await pdfApi.UploadPdf(pdf, "myapikey");
```

Comment: How do I implement the PdfFile class and the File class in the MainActivity? Kinda lost right now.

Comment: they are just C# class files.  Just add 2 new classes to your project and copy the code in

Comment: @Jason Yes, I already created 2 classes for PdfFile and File class, I also already have the interface for the API but I'm lost on how to call and send the data to the endpoint in the MainActivity. Can you show me how it's done? Sorry, I'm new and I'm still studying this. Thanks!

Comment: UploadPDF takes two parameters, a PdfFile and an API key, and it does not return any value;

Comment: @Jason I've added all my current code including the conversion of pdf to base64. Is this all correct?

Comment: @Jason I tried to run the program and having error locating my file

Could not find file "/C:\Users\STiFLER\Documents\RobertJohnUlepResume.pdf"

This is my code
                    var fullPath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\TEST.pdf";
                    
                    byte[] pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
                    string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);

Comment: your iOS/Android device has no idea what "c:\" is.  If you want to load a file it needs to be on the device's file system.

Comment: @Jason I've added the TEST.pdf file in the Assets folder in my android project. I used the FileSystem helper to read the pdf file and convert it to base64 but I'm now encountering "Name has invalid chars". Please see my last edit

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` has a **path** parameter, you are passing it a byte array.  `fileContents` already contains the file data, there is no need to use `ReadAllBytes`

Comment: @Jason Please see my last edit. When I tried to convert the pdf to base64 I encountered the status code 400 (Bad Request) error. I'm not sure if I'm using the right conversion method to base64. I attached screenshot of the converted pdf at the end